# Blink image render when video loaded

Tags: jquery, image, google-chrome, video, opera

I have a render problem that only happens in Chrome and Opera (I suspect Blink engine)

Whenever the main video loads, the images stop rendering normal.

Website: [Koperen Kees](http://jurienhamaker.net/koperenkees)

Anyone know what I can do about this problem?
It only happens in chrome and opera.
Safari, internet explorer and firefox render perfectly fine.

-- edit --

Safari doesn't work either...

-- edit --

added minimal page: http://jurienhamaker.net/koperenkees/fix-attempt

Comment: Please try to create a minimal example that illustrates your issue. This will be far easier for people to help you.

Comment: It just happens to this website I am creating right now, for the very first time, I don't know what is triggering this problem, and I don't know how to recreate it.. besides, the website is only one page and not finished yet, there isn't much content.

Comment: Take your page and selectively remove parts of it until either it's small enough to post a compact example here or the issue disappears. This will probably help you determine potential issues.

Comment: Thanks, I added a minimal page here:
http://jurienhamaker.net/koperenkees/fix-attempt

Comment: If you open your browser's dev tools (F12) you will see a variety of errors. I'd suggest attempting to remove these before proceeding.

For example, this doesn't load: https://www.youtube.com/get_video?noflv=1&video_id=-b-DczHWGPs&cpn=9kUT1krdeQvcGudD&el=embedded&referrer&eurl=http%3A%2F%2Fjurienhamaker.net%2Fkoperenkees%2Ffix-attempt%2F&fmt=243&ptk=youtube_none&autoplay=1&splay=1

Comment: That's actually caused by the youtube api itself, the url is nowhere to be found before the api loads (try disabling javascript)

Target-densitydpi is only mobile supported atm, hence why it's giving the error in the console log.

I don't see any other errors.